# !Package biblatex Error: Patching \MakeLowercase failed

Tags: biblatex

I had a working LaTeX file with `biblatex` referencing but after an update of the packages on July 3, 2022, including a package called `biblatex-chicago` my LaTeX code that worked yesterday produces the following 2 errors (from the log file):

> ```
> ! Package biblatex Error: Patching \MakeLowercase failed.
> See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
> Type H <return> for immediate help.
> ...
> l.212 \begin{document}
> This is an internal issue typically caused by a conflict
> between biblatex and some other package. Modifying
> the package loading order may fix the problem.
> ```

There's another error that regarding `\MakeLowercase`.

I've tried going through the biblatex manual but can't find any `\MakeUppercase` or `\MakeLowercase` reference relevant to this error.

Any help appreciated as I am completely at loss

Comment: For information: I've reinstalled MacTex and my latex code works again. So I am pretty sure that one of the updates causes this error. I simply can't tell which one.

Comment: It's a bug/incompatibility created by the last kernel update. Will be fixed Really Soon. (Just relying, I learnt about it in the chatroom).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update

The error should be resolved and original functionality should be restored in `biblatex` v3.18b and above if you use the LaTeX kernel at least 2022-06-01-PL5 and `expl3` at least 2022-07-14.

If you are still experiencing this problem, update your TeX system thoroughly and completely.

---

### Old answer

This is an issue caused by the new definition of `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` in LaTeX 2022-06-01-PL4 which landed in TeX Live on 2022-07-03.

An emergency update (`biblatex` v3.18a, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1233) is available in TeX Live (it landed in TeX Live a day later on 2022-07-04, because the update deadline was narrowly missed).

If you update today, you should get a version of `biblatex` that no longer has this error.

Note that the emergency fix simply disables the patch, so it is theoretically possible that your document does not come out as desired, though I rather suspect that the patch is not relevant for the vast majority of users. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1234 for progressing on re-enabling the patch.

Comment: Many thanks for this quick reply. This indeed resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it is 2023 and the answer of @moewe is not applicable. The error may be due to old biblatex config / style files in the local directory which apparently are no longer compatible with the current version of LaTeX.